# How to numerically solve for the steady state of a spatially dependent PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Apologies if this question is vague, I’m happy to rephrase if so.
I have a problem that can be expressed as a time and 2 spatial dimensions PDE:
$$
∂_t f = A∂_x f + B∂_y f + Cf+D,
$$
Where A, B, C and D are constants. (This is a simplified statement of the PDE to just make my point). I would like to solve for the steady state in x
and y
of f
. I do this by setting the time derivative on the left hand side to zero and trying to solve the resulting PDE in (x,y)
. My question is about the best way to solve that PDE.

Naively, I thought I would just rearrange to make the x derivative the subject and then just solve as I would if it were a time derivative on the left hand side. However, this feels wrong and I wonder if there’s a more elegant way.

Would anyone be able to point me in the direction of methods that are sometimes used to solve these problems? I checked numerical recipes but all the PDE methods they have are time dependent ones.

Note: this question was previously asked on Physics Stack Exchange but was voted off topic as was more of a maths question

Comment: It depends a lot on your domain. Finite differences and finite volumes are typically used for first-order equations. One problem you may run into is that if you set $\partial_t f=0$ ans solve the resulting discretized system, the solution you get may not be stable in the sense that it would not be obtained in the limit as $t\to\infty$. Most methods that actually find steady-state solutions do so by discretizing in time as well and stepping forward in time until things stop moving.

Answer (score 0):

### Some thoughts

One idea that comes to my mind is to formulate the PDE as a transport equation, i.e.
$$\partial_t f = \vec{v}\cdot \nabla f$$

with $\vec{v}\equiv \begin{pmatrix}A& B\end{pmatrix}^\intercal$, and lets assume $C=D=0$ for the moment. The Cauchy problem associated to the equation is to find $f\in V(\Omega)\times \mathbb{R}^+$ for $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ such that
$$\begin{cases}
\partial_t f = \vec{v}\cdot \nabla f\\
f=f_\Gamma(t) \text{ on }\Gamma_{in}\subset\partial \Omega\\
f(\vec{x},0)= f_0(\vec{x})
\end{cases}$$

and admits a solution of this form: $f_0(\vec{x}+\vec{v}t)$. You can observe, how $\vec{v}$ dictates the direction of the transport of the initial solutoin $f_0$ on the domain $\Omega$. For this problem you would usually opt for an "upwind scheme" if you like finite difference methods, or for something like a steamline-upwind Petrov-Galerkin method ("SUPG") if you like Finite Element methods.

Now you have cancelled out your time derivative, meaning that the initial solution you prescribe is stationary. The simple problem to find $f$ such that
$$\vec{v}\cdot \nabla f = 0$$

is solved by all spatially constant functions $f(\vec{x},t)=g(t)$. There are other solutions too, depending on $\vec{v}$ (i.e. depending on $A,B$). For exampe, if $\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}^\intercal$, then $f:(\vec{x},t)\mapsto (x,-y)$ solves your problem too.

If you include another term, i.e.
$$\vec{v}\cdot \nabla f +Cf= 0$$

then you are technically looking at a PDE in two variables, but either by choosing $\vec{v}\equiv \begin{pmatrix}1&0\end{pmatrix}^\intercal$ or by applying a coordinate transformation into a coordinate system, where one of the componentes of $\vec{v}$ vanish will give you an ODE of first order! For this you can basically apply something like an Euler method, or you just solve it analytically. In both cases, you need a suitable initial condition. Adding the constant $D$ does not change a lot now, the idea still works.

### Conclusion

You see, that without knowing the values of your constants, its hard to give you a very concrete answer. Moreover, depending on your constants, you might not yield a well-posed problem (= a problem that certainly has a unique solution etc.). In addition to the constants, we also need to know what boundary and initial values you want to prescribe.